# iOS, iPhone, Bluetooth discovery during call

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-device-discovery

I am experiencing issues while trying to connect iOS app with a BLE device, during a call.
While not on a call the connection works fine and the phone and the BLE board connect instantaneously, however if there is a call, it's almost like the BT discovery is turned off completely.
I looked up everywhere and on Apple dev and couldn't find any info about changes to the discovery or BT antenna attenuation, during a call.
Does anyone have any ideas or any links they could point me to ?
Thank you !

Comment: Is this your own app or an app from the app store? Do you know if the app supports background processing?

Comment: Yes, to both. Problem is also only with certain vehicles.